# Control where table returned by ajax call is placed in the website?

Tags: html, ajax

I have my Ajax call:

```
$(function(){
    $("#refresh1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"TableRefresh.php",

            success:function(response){
                $("#results").html(response);
            }
        });
    });                      
})
```

`TableRefresh.php` just creates and prints an HTML table with printf() statements, but when it prints it back on the page it sticks it at the very top. How can I control where it puts it? (the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableRefresh.php` doesn't print anything.

in the `success` function you are adding the results to a element `#results` if you want the results somewhere else in the page simply change the selector.

Comment: It actually does print, I have printf statements within it to print out a table. Is there any way to adjust where these get printed?

Comment: the results from a `ajax call` comes back as a string (in your case assigned to the var `response`) no matter what method you use on the server to print it. with `$("#results").html(response)` you are setting the innerHTML of the div with id `results` to the value the server returned

Comment: Alright I understand. Seems there was some confusion there by me. Thank you!